# How to read data on the main thread from a file being read on a worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrent-programming

I am processing a huge data file as "posted below", and I read it on a separate thread. And in the main thread i want to retrieve some data frm that file such as `logFile.getFileHash.getTimeStamp` to perform some operation on that timeStamp. The problem ia m facing is that, how to start reading some data from my file in the main thread only when my file is completely read in that other thread?

note: i do not want to do my operations on the data retrieved ffrom the file on the same thread that reads the file, i want to do so on the main thread.

**example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//fileThread.start(); will take 8 seconds.
/*
 *here i want to read some data from my file to perform some processing but only
 *when the thread that handles reading the file finishes work.
 }
```

**file**

```
private static void processFile(File dataFile) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MeasurementFile logfile = new MeasurementFile(dataFile);
    System.out.println(logfile.getTotalLines());
  System.out.println(logfile.getFileHash().get(logfile.getTotalLines()).getFullParameters().length);
    System.out.println(logfile.getFileHash().get(logfile.getTotalLines()).getEngineSpeed());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CountDownLatch to wait until the reader finishes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Answer (score 1):

[Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) can fit this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

fileThread.start(); 
fileThread.join();
//..now this thread blocks until *fileThread* exits

}
```

Comment: This works only when the worker thread ends after reading the file. If it's supposed to do some other work then it's not the best match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but I think you are trying to make the main thread read the same file after the child thread has done reading it without ending the child thread. If that's so then you can create a synchronized readMyFile(File file) method that any thread can use to read any file, of course making sure the child thread reads the file first.

Comment: thank you fo rthe answer, i hink i need to do something like synchronizatio. given the code above ca you please show me how to use synchronize?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.

If what I assumed was correct then you could do something like this, roughly...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ...
    fileThread.start();

    synchronized (fileThread) {
        try{
            fileThread.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ...
    MyReader.readMyFile(file);
    ...
}
```

... And the fileThread thread class something as ...

```
class FileThread extends Thread {

public void run() {

    synchronized (this){
        ...
        MyReader.readMyFile(file);
        notify();
        ...
    }
}
```

This is one way. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you fr the answer. would you pease provide some explanation how it works, and how the main thread and the file thread are synchronized?

Answer (score -1):

Add an attribute in the file thread and a public getter for it. When that thread finishes, change isFinished's value to true;

```
private boolean finished = false;
public isFinished(){...}
```

In your main thread, just sleep it and resume it to check if file thread has finished:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ...
    fileThread.start();
    ...
    while(!fileThread.isFinished()){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);//1 second or whatever you want
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    //Do something
    ....
}
```

Comment: `finished` should be at least volatile. This is not thread-safe

Comment: Wrong. Volatile is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads, not the case as the main thread will only read it.
This solution is completely thread-safe, in fact, you're just communicating threads with a variable only modified by one of them.

Comment: Not really. What we have here is the main thread reading the variable and the file thread modifying it. If there are two threads accessing one variable (even if only one of them writes to it), then the variable has to be volatile. This is required by the java memory model. Otherwise (without volatile) the jvm is free to cache the value of non-volatile variable and never let the main thread observe any value written to it by a different thread.